# Docker: Can't Find my_app Module

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am creating an flask app to demo Cloudbuild and Docker.

Here is my file structure:

[image: file_structure]

When I build and try to run my docker image, I keep getting an error:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app'**

Here is my main.py file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from faker import Faker
import random

app = Flask(__name__)
fake = Faker()

# Function to generate fake employee data
def create_employee():
    return {
        "id": random.randint(1000, 9999),
        "name": fake.name(),
        "address": fake.address(),
        "email": fake.email(),
        "job_title": fake.job()
    }

# In-memory list to hold employees
employees = [create_employee() for _ in range(10)]

# Route to display a list of employees
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', employees=employees)

# Route to add a new employee and redirect to index
@app.route('/add-employee', methods=['GET'])
def add_employee():
    employees.append(create_employee())
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

And here is my DockerFile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set the working directory in the container to /app
WORKDIR /my_app/

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY ./my_app /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Make port 5000 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run app.py when the container launches
# CMD ["python", "app.py"]

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8080", "--workers", "1", "--threads", "8", "my_app.main:main"]
```

For more context: Originally, the main.py file was at the root folder. I was having issues with finding modules in the main.py file for testing, so I decided to move the main.py file and other folders into the "my_app" folder.

Comment: In your Dockerfile check to where you set your workdir and where you COPY folders.

Comment: What am I doing wrong? Isn't the working directory for this structure /my_app?

Comment: Think about it, you are setting a working director within your container to `my_app`, and then you're copying from your local folder `my_app` into `app`. Where did `app` come from all of a sudden?